# How to loop through unique combinations of 2 categorical variables to create several animated plots?

Tags: r, loops, gganimate

I'm looking to loop through unique combinations of two categorical variables to create animated bubble plots in R. I'm gonna use example data to I don't overcomplicate anything. Note: Ignore that there is only one unique ID.

Lets say I have a data frame with the following information:

```
#Create data frame
DF <- data.frame("frameId" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
"CV1" = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
 "CV2" = c("I","J","K","I","J","K","I","J","K","I","J","K","I","J","K","I","J","K"),
 "X"=10:27,"Y"=30:47,"ID"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I've created an animated bubble plot for one combination of "CV1" and "CV2", which was where "CV1" = "A" and "CV2"="I".

```
#Create subset of one unique combination of the categorical variables
S1<- subset(DF, CV1=="A" &CV2 =="I",select=frameId:ID)

#Create animated bubble plot with gganimate
P1<-ggplot(S1, aes(X, Y, color = ID)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  theme_bw() +
  # gganimate specific bits:
  labs(title = 'frameId: {frame_time}', x = 'X', y = 'Y') +
  transition_time(frameId) +
  ease_aes('linear')
#animate the plot
animate(P1)
#Save the plot to my files
anim_save("Plot_1.gif")
```

I want to create this animated bubble plot for each unique combination of "CV1" and "CV2", and then save it with a unique name. How can I write a loop function to do this?

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: The code doesn't run for me with the given data, getting error `Error in if (times[1] <= 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Using gganimate 1.0.7

Comment: Enr89, you are almost there. Wrap your code into a function to which you supply the dataframe, and variable for CV1 and CV2. Code your filename subject to this combination of variables - otherwise you will overwrite `Plot_1.gif` with every run of the loop. Then iterate over CV1/CV2.

Comment: @JonSpring: I apologize, there was an issue with the data frame. I fixed the issue and updated the code, it'll run now!

Comment: Try something like creating a data.frame to iterate through using ```expand.grid(CV1 = unique(DF$CV1), CV2 = unique(DF$CV2))```. ```expand.grid``` takes a number of vectors and creates the cartesian product of those vectors in the form of a data.frame.